# Unable to apply custom pipe to high chart tooltip values

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am trying to implement the tooltip for whisker bloxplotchart highchart in my angular4 application.

I am trying to apply the custom pipe that i have written but it doesnt seem to apply here in highcharts. Is there a different way of doing it in high charts.
My custom pipe basically converts numbers that are in thousands to 100K for example and millions to 100M  etc. I have shared my code for the custom pipe as well as highchart component

I am trying this in my tooltip but it doesnt seem to apply.. The value is coming blank {point.high |ShortNumberFormat}

Not sure what i am doing wrong ? Please find my code below.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ShortNumberFormatPipe } from '@wtw/toolkit';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-box-plot-chart',
    template: '<chart [options]="options" (load)="getInstance($event.context)"></chart>',
    styles: [`
        chart{
              display: block;
              width: 100% !important;
              padding:0;
        }
    `]
})
export class BoxPlotChartComponent {
    private _x = new ShortNumberFormatPipe();

    public options: any;
    chart: any;

    @Input() public series: any;
    @Input() public moduleName: string = '';

    constructor() {

        this.options = {

            chart: {
                type: 'boxplot'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }, plotLines: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true,
                headerFormat: '<strong style="font-size:12px;color:{point.color}">{point.key}</strong><br><br><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td  style="font-size:10px;">Maximum: </td>' +
                                 '<td style="font-size:10px;"><b>{point.high |shortNumberFormat}</b></td></tr>' +
                              '<tr><td style="font-size:10px;">Upper quartile: </td>' +
                                 '<td style="font-size:10px;"><b>{point.q1} </b></td></tr>' +
                               '<tr><td style="font-size:10px;">Median: </td>' +
                                 '<td style="font-size:10px;"><b>{point.median} </b></td></tr>' +
                                '<tr><td style="font-size:10px;">Lower quartile: </td>' +
                                 '<td style="font-size:10px;"><b>{point.q3}   </b></td></tr>' +
                                 '<tr><td style="font-size:10px;">Minimum: </td>' +
                                 '<td style="font-size:10px;"><b>{point.low} </b></td></tr>' ,
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                valueDecimals: 0
            },
            series: []
        };
    }

    getInstance(chartInstance): void {
        this.chart = chartInstance;
        if(this.moduleName == 'npv'){
            this.options.tooltip.valueDecimals = 0;
        }

        this.redraw();
    }


    ngOnChanges(data: any) {
        if (!data.series.currentValue || !this.chart) return;
        data.series.currentValue.map(s => {
            this.chart.addSeries(s);
        });
        this.chart.reflow();
    }

    redraw() {
        if (!this.chart) return;
        this.chart.addSeries(this.series);


    }

}
```

Custom pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'shortNumberFormat'
})
export class ShortNumberFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(number: any, decimals = 0) {

    if (number === null) {
      return;
    }

    number = parseFloat(number);

    if (isNaN(number)) {
      return;
    }

    if (isNaN(decimals)) {
      return;
    }

    const signPrefix = number < 0 ? '-' : '';
    number = Math.abs(number);

    if (number <= 999) { // hundreds
      number = number.toFixed(decimals);
    } else if (number >= 1000 && number <= 999999) {  // thousands
      number = (number / 1000).toFixed(decimals) + 'K';
    } else if (number >= 1000000 && number <= 999999999) { // millions
      number = (number / 1000000).toFixed(decimals) + 'M';
    } else { // billions
      number = (number / 1000000000).toFixed(decimals) + 'B';
    }

    return signPrefix + number;
  }
}
```

After failed attempts of transforming the values via graph, I tried it at the component level but unfortunately the component doesnt understand string so it doesnt render the graph. If i comment the assignment it renders correctly.

```
this.results = this._npvResults.map((result: any) => {
      result.chartSeries.data.forEach(s => {
        s.high = this.shortNumberFormatPipe.transform(s.high,0),
        s.low = this.shortNumberFormatPipe.transform(s.low,0),
        s.median = this.shortNumberFormatPipe.transform(s.median,0),
        s.q1 = this.shortNumberFormatPipe.transform(s.low),
        s.q3 = this.shortNumberFormatPipe.transform(s.q3)

      });
      return createNpvAnalysisResult(result);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have this

```
pointFormat: '<tr><td  style="font-size:10px;">Maximum: </td>' +
                             '<td style="font-size:10px;"><b>{point.high |shortNumberFormat}</b></td></tr>' +
                          '<tr><td style="font-size:10px;">Upper quartile: </td>' +
                             '<td style="font-size:10px;"><b>{point.q1} </b></td></tr>' +
                           '<tr><td style="font-size:10px;">Median: </td>' +
                             '<td style="font-size:10px;"><b>{point.median} </b></td></tr>' +
                            '<tr><td style="font-size:10px;">Lower quartile: </td>' +
                             '<td style="font-size:10px;"><b>{point.q3}   </b></td></tr>' +
                             '<tr><td style="font-size:10px;">Minimum: </td>' +
                             '<td style="font-size:10px;"><b>{point.low} </b></td></tr>' ,
```

Particulary this point :

```
<td style="font-size:10px;"><b>{point.high |shortNumberFormat}</b></td></tr>
```

This bunch of code is **the chart code**, not *Angular code*.

You write your Angular code in **Typescript**. Here, you just write some code that will be processed (or not, I don't really know the library, but let's say it is processed) by the library.

Angular, on the other side, **compiles your code** as vanilla Javascript.

This means that once your applicatoin is built (or served), you can't update the Angular code anymore.

In this case, that is what you are trying to do. You try to give Angular code to your chart.

**You can't do that, it won't work**.

If you want to make it work, give it a raw number, like this.

```
'<td style="font-size:10px;"><b>' + new ShortNumberFormatPipe().transform(point.high) + '</b></td></tr>' +
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation so what is the solution for this ?

Comment: You calculate the value in your component, and put it in your string. No binding, no data extrapolation, just plain numbers in a string.

Comment: I tried the implementation in the component but the chart doesnt understand string so it doesnt render the graph.Please see the most updated. If i comment the assignments it reders correctly

Comment: I don't understand what you tried. For all I see, you just used the pipe in your component. You didn't change the string of your chart.

Comment: Sorry what do you meant by string in your chart

Comment: The very string you use in your chart that I put in my answer.

Comment: Are you referring to the pipe applied after the value . I have removed that in my solution that I am working locally

Comment: I really can't be more specific than that. All I have in my answer is a string that you used, where there is a pipe in it. I told you to get rid of the pipe in that and to display only raw numbers.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier the pipe was already removed from my local solution . I didn't update the post to avoid confusion for people who are reading it as I have made reference of that pipe . All I am trying to display is for e.g {point.high}. What is wrong in that ?

Comment: I already explained what is wrong with that. I edit my post to add the solution at the end, because you really seem to make no effort to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare your pipe in a module?

```
 import { FileSizePipe } from './filesize.pipe';

 @NgModule({
 declarations: [
 //...
    FileSizePipe ,
 ],
})

export class AppModule {}
```

https://toddmotto.com/angular-pipes-custom-pipes

Comment: I have been using this pipe all other places in my application . It works fine in other places in the UI. Yes it's in the app module